# I am trying to download zip file from a auto download link mentioned in the email body of Gmail using php

Tags: php, csv, email, curl, download

I get emails on gmail everyday from a vendor, with a link to auto download a zip folder of CSV files. I am trying to automate the database upload part by writing a script to access the email server, search for unread emails and then access the the link in the email body and then save the zip folder in a local directory such as the downloads folder and then import the CSV files to the database and eventually run this as a cron job. I have tried to write a script which does the above things(except the last part of importing the data from the CSV files to database) but was unable to access the link in the email to start auto download. I tried to use DOM document, curl, header and bunch of other stuff but wasn't able to get the script to do the same thing as I want. I am pasting my code below. I am unable to access the link in the email body and force a download of zip folder to local folder from that link. Kindly help me to achieve the above

```
<?php

/* connect to gmail */
$hostname = '{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX';
$username = 'example_email_address@gmail.com' ;
$password = 'password';

/* try to connect */
$inbox = imap_open($hostname,$username,$password) or die('Cannot connect to Gmail: ' . imap_last_error());

/* grab emails */
$emails = imap_search($inbox,'ALL');

/* if emails are returned, cycle through each... */
if($emails) {

    /* begin output var */
    $output = '';

    /* put the newest emails on top */
    rsort($emails);

    /* for every email... */
    foreach($emails as $email_number) {

        /* get information specific to this email */
        $overview = imap_fetch_overview($inbox,$email_number,0);
        $message = imap_fetchbody($inbox,$email_number,2);

        // $regex = '/\b(https?|ftp|file):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|$!:,.;]*[A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|$]/i';
        // preg_match_all($regex, $message, $matches);
        // $urls = $matches[0];
        // // go over all links
        // foreach($urls as $url) 
        //     {
        //         echo $url.'<br />';
        //     }

        // $dom = new DOMDocument;
        // //$dom->loadXML($message);
        // $dom->loadHTML($message);
        // $anchortags = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');
        // foreach ($anchortags as $anchortag) {
        //     echo $anchortag->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;
        //     preg_match('//([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?', $anchortag, $matches);
        //     }



        // /* output the email header information */
        // $output.= '<div class="toggler '.($overview[0]->seen ? 'read' : 'unread').'">';
        // $output.= '<span class="subject">'.$overview[0]->subject.'</span> ';
        // $output.= '<span class="from">'.$overview[0]->from.'</span>';
        // $output.= '<span class="date">on '.$overview[0]->date.'</span>';
        // $output.= '</div>';

        // /* output the email body */
        // $output.= '<div class="body">'.$message.'</div>';
    }

    echo $output;
} 

function get_data($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $timeout = 5;
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, $timeout);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $data;
}

$returned_content = get_data('https://dash-jci.s3.amazonaws.com/February_11_2017/Feb_11_2017-1486798132143.zip?response-cache-control=max-age%3D31536000&response-content-type=application%2Fzip&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAJREL4U5PR4NTGPKA&Expires=2135333220&Signature=8FxLAICc89HQMc98LQH6dsIYyp4%3Dfff');



/* close the connection */
imap_close($inbox);

?>
```

Comment: not sure what your actully stuck on

Comment: I am unable to access the link in the email body and force a download of zip folder to local folder from that link

Comment: your first / $regex ?

Comment: The first regex was only accessing a part of the whole link, apart from that I wanted to download a zip folder from that link to my local machine